# How do you repackage the gnu gcc standard libraries stdc++, gcc, and gcc_eh?

Tags: gcc, gnu, ld, std, libstdc++

Without modifying and recompiling the gnu gcc and stdc++ library builds, I need to be able to reproduce dynamic loading versions of those libraries with a different embedded soname.

I thought I would be clever and use the available static versions and repackage them with something like this:
`ld -E -shared -static "-lstdc++" -lgcc -lgcc_eh -o librepackaged_standard.so`

librepacked_standard.so is created, without warnings or errors, but ldd reports its not a dynamic library and readelf reports only these basic symbols:

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 4 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000201000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS __bss_start
     2: 0000000000201000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _edata
     3: 0000000000201000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _end
```

I am unsure why ld isn't bringing in all of the symbols defined statically.  I also don't know if there are any other special parameters I need to give it for this to work.

Another option is if there is a know cross platform way to simply change the soname embedded in the original elf libraries.  I'm currently only concerned with elf formatted binaries.  I am not interested in writting my own tool to change the .soname in existing binaries.

UPDATE:
The reason no symbols were getting compiled is because `ld` handles static binaries differently than .o files.  By default it does not import any symbols from the .a file unless they are required by a another library on the link line.  I fixed that by provided the --whole-archive option.

However that gives me another error, `relocation R_X86_64_32S against`_ZSt12_S_first_one' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`and` could not read symbols: Bad value` They are both from libstdc++.a in the bitset.o archive.  So I can't just recompile the .a's into a dynamic library because the GNU GCC compile, by default, does not compile the object files used for the static libraries with the PIC option.

That leaves me with finding an elf tool or recompiling GNU GCC with modifications to its build.

As stated by one of the answers, licensing issues could be a concern with any of these approaches.  My best answer is that we need to change to our requirements and find a different solution that doesn't involve changing or repackaging the GCC standard libraries in any fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason no symbols were getting compiled into the shared library is because `ld` handles static binaries differently than .o files. By default it does not import any symbols from the .a file unless they are required by a another library on the link line. The answer to that particular issue is to use the --whole-archive option and linking the .a files directly mostly works.

However, for this to work the .o files included in the static archive need to have been compiled using the -fPIC option at compile time.  However the object files used for the static libraries are not compiled with that option in the static libraries available.

So, the solution to changing the SONAME is to use an ELF binary utility or rebuilding GNU GCC modified to use different SONAMEs.

Since there are licensing concerns in this situation any of the solutions are not practical for the project because it is not open source and we do not want the requirement to redistribute a modified source version of GNU GCC for all our platforms.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `-static` probably undid the `-shared`.
2. Classically, you'd extract the object files from the static libraries and then package those object files into the shared library - relying on the universal use of PIC (position-independent code) so that the objects in the static libraries can safely be converted into a shared library.  You might be able to do without that extract step, but I doubt it.
3. You might want to think about whether you're meeting the licencing terms and conditions.

Comment: The ld man pages states for -static: Do not link against shared libraries.  <snip> You may use this option multiple times on the command line: it affects library searching for -l options  which  follow  it. <snip> This option can be used with -shared.  Doing so means that a shared library is being created but that  all of the library's external references must be resolved by pulling in entries from static libraries.

Comment: In reference to licensing, that is a good point to make to the people giving me the requirements.  I'm trying to convince them that the best option is to require a minimal version of the stdc++ library packages installed on supported platforms, which AFAIK is the common practice by software.